# Java : Jline3 : Autocomplete with more than one word

Tags: java, autocomplete, jline, jline3

I would like to auto complete using more than one word, for example:

```
> we can<TAB>
welcome_trashcan  pecan_seaweed  yeswecan  canwest
```

So all the suggestions should contain both of the keywords. Ideally, it should work for unlimited keywords.

I read the [completion wiki](https://github.com/jline/jline3/wiki/Completion), but I don't know which path to follow to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a new Interface (its written in groovy):

```java
class MatchAnyCompleter implements Completer {
    protected final List<Candidate> candidateList = []

    MatchAnyCompleter(List<String> list) {
        assert list
        list.each {
            candidateList << new Candidate(AttributedString.stripAnsi(it), it, null, null, null, null, true)
        }
    }

    @Override
    void complete(final LineReader reader, final ParsedLine commandLine, final List<Candidate> selected) {
        assert commandLine != null
        assert selected != null
        selected.addAll(candidateList.findAll {
            Candidate candidate ->
                commandLine.words().stream().allMatch {
                    String keyword ->
                        candidate.value().contains(keyword)
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
class MatchAnyCompleterTest extends Specification {
    def "Testing matches"() {
        setup:
            def mac = new MatchAnyCompleter([
                    "somevalue",
                    "welcome_trashcan",
                    "pecan_seaweed",
                    "yeswecan",
                    "canwest",
                    "nomatchhere"
            ])
            def cmdLine = new ParsedLine() {
                // non-implemented methods were removed for simplicity
                @Override
                List<String> words() {
                    return ["we","can"]
                }
            }
            List<Candidate> selected = []
            mac.complete(null, cmdLine, selected)
        expect:
            selected.each {
                println it.value()
            }
            assert selected.size() == 4
    }
}
```

output:

```
welcome_trashcan
pecan_seaweed
yeswecan
canwest
```